# How to put an image on top of a div (center horizontally but top vertically, in the middle)

Tags: html, css

I am writing a blog post (blogger) in which I wanna share a letter. The text of this letter I have put it in a div with a light grey color and a shadow on the right and bottom so it looks like a piece of paper.

My HTML says something like:

```
This is my post. Blah blah blah<br />
<br />
Here is more text, blah bla blah. And this is the letter:<br />
<br />
<div style="background-color: #f7f7f7; box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #DBDBDB; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 35px;">
28 August 2015<br />
<br />
This is the letter, blah blah blah.<br />
<br />
Here mor parragraphs of the letter, bla bla bla. <br />
<br />
```

This makes my post look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUNNL.png

Now, I want to add a digital washi tape (like a piece of cellotape) on top of my grey div, so it looks like the letter has been stuck there with the bit of cellotape.

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78kyz.jpg

How could I do this in the HTML? (I am writing directly in just one blogger blogspot)

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could try something like the following if you only can aply inline styles...

```html
This is my post. Blah blah blah<br />
<br />
Here is more text, blah bla blah. And this is the letter:<br />
<br /><br /><br />
<div style="background-color: #f7f7f7; box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #DBDBDB; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 35px;">
  <div style="width:50px; margin:0 auto">
  <img style="width:50px; position:absolute; margin:-60px auto 0;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue96u.jpg?s=328&g=1" />
</div>
28 August 2015<br />
<br />
This is the letter, blah blah blah.<br />
<br />
Here mor parragraphs of the letter, bla bla bla. <br />
<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the image in the div, give it an id or class, and give it the properties:
z-index:10; //or whatever number you want. What this does, it will bring this image in front of all other
position:absolute;
left: 50%; // it wil bring it in the middle.

```
<img src="image-src" style="z-index:10; position:absolute; left:50%">
```

Simplified version.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your letter div is positioned `relative`. To implement this digital wash tape just put another div in your letter div and position it `absolute`.
Something like that:
   `.cellotape {
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    left:500px;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pmqbn7rj/)

add this `.img` class to your image:

```
.img{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -60px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightcoral;
}
```

This will set your image position to relative, at the top of the letter, into its center.

You will have to add the image inside your letter like this:

```
<div class='letter'>
    <div class='img'></div>
    28 August 2015<br />
    <br />
    This is the letter, blah blah blah.<br />
    <br />
    Here mor parragraphs of the letter, bla bla bla. <br />
    <br />

</div>
```

Notice that I have `div` just to show you how to get things done.

Answer (score 0):

> You may need to adjust the left percent, height and width to suit your needs, but this should work for you

```
<style>
.topImg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 500px;
    height: 335px;
}
</style>



<img src="" class="topImg">
```